# Python rotation does not produce the same than manual rotation

Tags: python, scripting, transforms

I have 3 plank forming an equilateral triangle, I want to rotate them according to the triangle gravity center (where all the height intersect).

By hand I select them all, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, turn the mouse, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and voila, perfectly rotated.

I then wrote a script that does the exact same thing, however they are not rotated the same, the center of the second triangle is off.

```
def select_all():
    scn = bpy.context.scene
    print("deselecting all")
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    objs = [obj for obj in scn.objects if obj.name.startswith("plank")]
    for obj in objs:
        print("selecting object " + obj.name)
        obj.select = True

select_all()
bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=radians(180.0), axis=(0, 0, 1))
```

and here is an image of the results :

[image]

Why isn't the rotation being the same?